# How to indent symbol list in sublime-text?

Tags: symbols, sublimetext, indentation

Among other things, I'm using sublime-text to write stories. Those files have become large, obviously. So I decided to use custom syntax files to make it all easier to read; and now recently `*.tmPreferences` files as well to make headlines become available as symbols. I can now use "Goto Symbol" to jump faster up and down, which is pretty neat.

But I don't know how to indent that list.

There is [this documentation](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/metadata.html) which describes the `increaseIndentPattern` setting – but that is for indentation of the file content, not the symbol list.

I have a complex markdown file for comparison with content like this:

```markdown
# Readme

Introductory text sounds like lorem ipsum.

## Installation

Abc def.

## Usage

### Use the force

Help us, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're our only hope.

### Save the cheerleader

Save the world.

## Dependencies

Pull my finger.
```

In the content, the headlines all start directly at the beginning without whitespace. And yet, sublime somehow manages to display them in a hierarchy in the symbol list.

Unfortunately, I cannot find anywhere (on Ubuntu22, build `4152` installed via `apt-get`) where the sublime-text app stores its own `*.tmPreference` file for markdown.

Answer (score 1):

To see and edit the shipped packages, it is recommended to use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit. Once OverrideAudit is installed:

- open Command Palette
- type `OA: OR`
- select `OverrideAudit: Open Resource`
- navigate to the `Markdown` package
- select `Symbol List - Heading.tmPreferences`
- observe the `symbolTransformation` key/value pair. It takes `sed`-style regexes (albeit Oniguruma compatible syntax) and executes them in sequence to transform the text as you desire for inclusion in the symbol list.

If it is easier for your syntax/use-case, you could have different `tmPreferences` files targeting more specific scopes rather than having to have lots of complex regex replacement expressions.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Seems like Markdown doesn't use complex logic, like I had thought – it just adds two spaces for each hash. I misinterpreted the capabilities of `tmPreferences` files, then.